# UITabBars - "should be accessible from every location in the application."

Tags: ios

The iOS GUI guidelines say of a UITabBar that " ... and should be accessible from every location in the application."

What does accessible mean? If it means visible why don't they say visible?
If it doesn't mean visible what does it mean in practice?

I would like to have a table view whose contents are filtered according to which tab the user presses on a tab bar, but if the user selects a table view item to obtain its details, or goes into an edit mode I want the tab bar to disappear.
Is this permitted according to "and should be accessible from every location in the application."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accesible means whatever they want it to mean ... and it is, to some extent, up to the individual reviewer.

If you look at the ipod/music app, you'll see that they don't always have the tab bar showing, but it's never more than one touch away, e.g., when you select a track, the track takes up the whole screen but `back` takes you back to the tab bar controller.

The main thing they seem to be trying to discourage is a tab bar controller that leads to a navigation controller. They seem to feel that mixing the two abstractions is confusing.

Comment: Thank you - my detail view would be a web page, which could lead to a chain of other web pages navigated via a navigation controller. That would be the scenario you described - however it might (hopefully) be argued that once the user has entered the first web page then they are in a different mode and going to another page is a continuation of that same mode. Guess won't know until submission.

Comment: That sounds like the case they're trying to discourage but I couldn't say whether this is enough to trigger a rejection.